# Method call in opt box's guard

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

```
A::foo() {
    if (B::bar())
        doSomething();
}
```

How can I show that `B::bar()` method call in an UML sequence diagram? I know it is possiable as this:

```
A::foo() {
    x = B::bar();
    if (x)
        doSomething();
}
```

So that I can draw the message first, then the opt box with [x] guard. But this isn't exactly the same. Is there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not fall into the trap to program graphically. SDs are not meant to picture complex algorithms (it will fail as you can easily guess after doing some nested `if`s with fragments).

If the `x`-assignment is part of some more complex structure you  can use it in the fragment as it is and eventually adorn it with a note telling how and where the `x` has been set. If it's just what you have above you can simply use the source of the `x` in the fragment (namely the `B::bar()`).

Comment: If I use the later, should I still draw the method call message?

Comment: That's probably not needed as the signature you'd use in the guard is already distinct. However, if you want to point out that assignment for some reason place the message in front, although the message itself will not tell where the result will go (namely into `x`).

Comment: I add one, I think that "are not meant to picture complex algorithms" is a real good one.